# How do I make VLC play a HEVC video properly?

Tags: vlc

I installed the plugin using this

```
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
```

and it has started working. But the video quality is absolutely horrible: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNofX.jpg  (both the pictures are supposed to be split)

Did I just get a bad video file, or is this the fault of the plugin?

If not, how do I convert a HEVC to MP4?

Comment: whats the Resolution of the video and also whats your computer specs. HEVC requires a lot of processing power especially if its a 1080 resolution

Comment: It's 1080p and I don't have a really great laptop.


2 GB RAM

2.30GHz processor 

64-bit

Comment: Try running 480p and 720p video to see if its the problem with plugin or your hardware

Answer (score 0):

To see is problem in plug-in reinstall it then run that file. 
If you want to convert video to MP4 use OpenShotVideoEditor you can download it in your ubuntu software center. Open that video with it then go
**File/Export video...** then choose which format you want to convert and press ok. If you need more help text me.

Comment: How do I reinstall the plugin, exactly? I'm sorry, but I'm absolutely new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Use this command (sudo apt-get purge vlc-data)
then again install  your plugin.

Comment: Reinstalling didn't help. So I'm trying to convert it now to mpeg.

Comment: Is convert working?

Comment: It converted successfully, but now it's not even displaying the video and the audio is weird (of the converted file). The old file plays the same way. Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: Try this:                                                                                                                         (sudo apt-add-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265 )--
(sudo apt-get update )--
(sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265)

Comment: Insert this to your terminal one by one.

Comment: The video is playing, however with a horrible quality. Btw, I really appreciate you helping me.

Comment: No prob. I see you are new on ubuntu i  just crated youtube channel for tutorials. If you want you can subscribe and you can see in future many things about Ubuntu.